NavigationStack for iOS15.0+
I am trying to create a kind of Coordinator that stacks the views while navigating and make it compatible from iOS 15.0.
Here is my code that works for the first push to the next view but after going to the 3rd view, it returns to the first one...
I am open to any advise but I have to maintain the compatibility for iOS15.
Here is my code:
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class FlowCoordinator: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var selection: String?
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        addOberver()
    }
    
    func showView(_ view: String) {
        selection = view
    }
    
    func addOberver() {
        $selection
            .sink { newString in
            print(newString ?? "")
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func repeatPrints() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
            print(self.selection ?? "")
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var coordinator = FlowCoordinator()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MainListScreen()
                .navigationTitle("Main List")
        }
        .environmentObject(coordinator)
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
    
}

struct MainListScreen: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: FlowCoordinator

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: MealDetailsScreen(),
                           tag: "MealDetailsScreen",
                           selection: $coordinator.selection) {
                EmptyView()
            }

            Button(action: {
                coordinator.showView("MealDetailsScreen")
            }) {
                Text("Go to Meal Details")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MealDetailsScreen: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: FlowCoordinator

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: MealMultimediaScreen(),
                           tag: "MealMultimediaScreen",
                           selection: $coordinator.selection) {
                EmptyView()
            }

            Button(action: {
                coordinator.showView("MealMultimediaScreen")
            }) {
                Text("Go to Meal Multimedia")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Meal Details")
    }
}

struct MealMultimediaScreen: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: FlowCoordinator
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Last View"),
                           tag: "Text",
                           selection: $coordinator.selection) {
                EmptyView()
            }

            Button(action: {
                coordinator.showView("Text")
            }) {
                Text("Go to Text")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Meal Multimedia")
    }
    
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}



When you push the 3rd view, coordinator.selection gets updated to MealMultimediaScreen which doesn't match the first link's tag MealDetailsScreen & pops the view back.
This navigation approach with tags & selection only works for a single view since a view can't navigate to multiple destinations at the same time, & it would require you to have a separate FlowCoordinator for every destination View.
I suggest you work with NavigationLink(_:destination:isActive:) instead as you can manipulate the isActive parameter based on a stack:
final class FlowCoordinator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var stack = [String]()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private func pop(to tag: String) {
        while stack.contains(tag) {
            _ = stack.popLast()
        }
    }
    func isActive(for tag: String) -> Binding<Bool> {
        return Binding {
            return self.stack.contains(tag)
        } set: { newValue in
            if !newValue {
                self.pop(to: tag)
            }else {
                self.stack.append(tag)
            }
        }
    }
    func push(_ tag: String) {
        stack.append(tag)
    }
    func pop() {
        _ = stack.popLast()
    }
}

Then you create a NavigationLink wrapper that handles the coordinator:
struct NavigationLinkView<Content: View>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var coordinator: FlowCoordinator
    private let destination: Content
    private let tag: String
    init(tag: String, destination: Content) {
        self.destination = destination
        self.tag = tag
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(isActive: coordinator.isActive(for: tag)) {
            destination
        } label: {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}

Usage:
NavigationLink(tag: "MealDetailsScreen", destination: MealDetailsScreen())

Note: This might be helpful If you want an implementation similar to iOS 16's navigationDestination & NavigationStack.

Thanks a lot @Timmy. As soon as I get to home, will try your answer.
